# Flex 3: Error: Repeater is not executing... i know why, but i dont know how to fix it

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, repeater

I have the following code:

```
<mx:Repeater id="showNames" dataProvider="{parentApplication.bfa1aStudents}">
    <mx:Text text="{parentApplication.getStudentName(showNames.currentItem)}" color="#8ab534" click="nameSelected(Number(showNames.getRepeaterItem(showNames.currentIndex)));" selectable="false" mouseOver="parentApplication.switchCursor(true);" mouseOut="parentApplication.switchCursor(false);" />
</mx:Repeater>
```

I know you can't use currentItem or currentIndex on a click... and that this problem is fixed with the getRepeaterItem() function, but I'm not sure exactly how to use it.  The DP is a bunch of numbers, representing user IDs if that matters.  If anybody can help me out with my "click" portion of the text, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first, you shouldn't use `parentApplication`.  It's a horrible practice which couples your view to that application class.  Second, why aren't you just using a list if all you're doing is just showing text.

Comment: So how would i reference items and functions that are used on several different layers (parents, children, etc...) throughout the application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem()` for click instead of showNames

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping your Text components in a VBox.  Like JAX said, there are some other issues you may want to consider addressing also.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
event.currentTarget.selectedItem.data
```

in your click handler.